# How can I randomize a text itemization in ConTeXt?

Tags: lists, context

I've defined my item groups as:

```
\defineitemgroup[institm]
 \setupitemgroup[institm][1][text][symbol=2, indentnext=no, ]
```

And

```
\startinstitm
{\bf Contributors }     
\item Foo Pty Ltd {\sc nsw}
\item Bar Pty Ltd {\sc vic}
\stopinstitm
```

This produces a very lovely "block" of text. However, the "random" command does not seem to be working in version: `2012.05.30 11:26` Is it worth the effort of moving away from TeXlive to get the random command working?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To randomize itemize you need to enclose each item in a `\startitem` ... `\stopitem`. For example (I made a few stylistic changes in your code):

```
\defineitemgroup[institm]

\setupinstitm[1][text, random]
\setupinstitm[1][symbol=2, indentnext=no]

\starttext

\bold{Contributions}
\startinstitm
  \startitem Foo Pvt Ltd {\sc nsw} \stopitem
  \startitem Bar Pvt Ltd {\sc vic} \stopitem
  \startitem Baz Pvt Ltd {\sc abc} \stopitem
\stopinstitm

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: How can I remove linebreaks between items with this?

Comment: I am using ConTeXt 2012.07.19 and I don't get any line breaks between items.

Comment: Do you have newlines before the symbols?

Comment: I have added an image showing the result that I get (which actually shows a bug in the randomization)!